# How do I get my stuff off a non-working Ubuntu machine?

Tags: data-recovery, reinstall

So, I've somehow managed to wreck my Ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 16.04) by installing some software.

Now, when I try to log in, the screen just goes black for a bit and then takes me back to log in screen. Same happens when I try to log in with a different desktop environment, as I was using Gnome Shell instead of the Unity environment.

I can, however, log in as a guest but it won't connect to the internet.

So, can someone please advise me as to the best method for recovering all my stuff? I want to get all my stuff off then reinstall Ubuntu 17. I don't suppose there's any way to do this as a guest, or will I need to do it via BIOS or some other thing?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to user another bootable ubuntu USB stick/CD and then trying the live boot. After the computer is booted, the open the terminal and type `lsblk`
 This will show all your hard drives on your computer. Mount the hard drive to `/mnt` using `mount /dev/sda<your_hard_drive_no> /mnt`. Now you can copy all the data to another storage media by visiting /mnt directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot with Ubuntu Live CD / USB and backup your stuff. But before that try to recover your system by setting right ownership to your home directory. To do this press ctrl + alt + f1 key combination to enter console mode and type your username and password. After you are logged type:

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) ~
```

where the `$(id ...)` commands produce your actual username and reboot by type:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```